# Detecting upside down numbers in the MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying to predict numbers using the MNIST dataset. Since I don't know whether the numbers that I'm trying to predict are rotated (most of the time upside down, but can also be 90 or 270 degrees), I've trained a second model to try to figure out the rotation before actually trying to classify the numbers. That second model is fed with the MNIST training set in all four rotations and according classifications:

```
(x_train_orig, _), (_, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = []
y_train = []
for img in x_train_orig:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        x_train.append(np.rot90(img, i))
        y_train.append(i)
shuffle_idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_train))
x_train = np.array(x_train)[shuffle_idx]
y_train = np.array(y_train)[shuffle_idx]
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ])
batch_size = 128
epochs = 10

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)
```

When running the prediction against the MNIST test set, it is performing very well. But when I try to predict my own numbers, it seems unusable. In the following example the first four A-D are random 5's from the MNIST test set (all predictions correct) and the second four E-H are 5's from my own data (all predictions wrong).

[image]

I have a hard time understanding why it is not working with my own data and also why all four are wrongly classified as being rotated 180 degrees. Am I missing something?

Also worth noting: Using the exact same processing of the images for the actual classification of the numbers into 0-9 the prediction is working very well.

Comment: I thought most MNIST classifiers were quite specific to the MNIST digit data and did a poor job of generalizing to other datasets with handwritten digits.

Comment: @Dave It is working pretty good in my case; I'm trying to process my own data in a way as similar as possible to the MNIST dataset (28x28, normalized to the same range, padding, all black background, etc).

Comment: Visually, your dataset's numbers look thinner than MNIST. I wonder if [dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.grey_dilation.html#scipy.ndimage.grey_dilation) would help?

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried different dilations but unfortunately the results did not improve.